# How is Themiscyra populated?

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

Do they have to reproduce to maintain a population from when Zeus created it and present day? If so, who are the fathers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the film we only see one young Amazonian, **Diana** and we got to know in the end that she is

> the daughter of Zeus

and rest of the Amazonian seems to be older than her and we can assume all were created by Gods. So I think they didn't reproduce and they are all immortal (until killed) as their comics counterpart.

But [in comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazons_(DC_Comics)#The_New_52) they did reproduce:

> In **The New 52** :The Amazons are said to have infrequently invaded ships coming near their island and forced themselves on the sailors, before killing them. After nine months, the birth of the resulting female children was highly celebrated and they were inducted into the ranks of the Amazons while the male children were rejected. In order to save the male children from being drowned to death by the Amazons, Hephaestus traded weapons to the Amazons in exchange for them.

But it isn't mentioned in films. So it will be just assumptions for now.

Comment: That's quite a bit darker than the movie's take. 

Comment: It's definitely time for me to go home... For a split second I actually though "huh, weird how the Amazons let the men give birth to the children on their island"...

Comment: Note that prior to the New 52 event in comics, they did not reproduce as described by [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75895/12783).

Answer (score 8):

It's specifically stated in the movie that Diana is the **only** child ever "born" on Themiscyra.

We also know that the Amazons are essentially immortal although they age but *really* slowly. We see Diana grow from a young child but we don't actually know how long that takes.

So do they reproduce in the DCEU?

## No

...at least not without divine intervention.

Comment: I think they stated in the movie that the Amazons didn't start out on Thermiscyra, they ended up there after the war, so it stands to reason that while none were ever born there, it doesn't mean that the weren't born elsewhere

Comment: The question is about *maintaining* the population on the island...not where the Amazons came from originally.

Comment: The question in the title is "How is it populated", and the answer is "it was populated when they moved there initially".  The question inside the body is "do they have to reproduce to maintain their population" and the answer is "Up until they were attacked, they didn't because they didn't have attrition".  You have stated that they do not reproduce in the DCEU, and I don't think that was ever stated that they don't ever reproduce,t hey just haven't on the island because there are no men, so there's no way *to* reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

**No, the Amazons of Themyscira have no need to maintain the population as they do not age.**

As told to Diana by her mother Hippolyta, the Amazons were created by Zeus as an army to defend mankind from the corruptions of Ares. After casting Ares from Olympus, Zeus then created Themyscira for them as a place where time & disease could not touch them. And lastly, we know that Hippolyta and her sister Antiope took part in the original battle against Ares' forces, and have not visibly aged since that time. Therefore, it is safe to assume that the Amazons on the island are the original ones created by Zeus.

This matches the comics version of Themyscira prior to the "New 52" reboot, with most of the Amazons on the island being alive since the days of ancient Greece. They did, however - from time to time - adopt girls into their culture as well.